# How to get the count of values that are present in object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the count of occurrences in the below object.

```
arr = [{"name":"rahul","age":23}, {"name":"Jack","age":22},{"name":"James","age":23}]
```

From the above array obj I want to get the count of people whose age is 23. In this case the expectation is 2.

I tried:

```
myArray.filter(x => x == searchValue).length;
```

But didn't get the exact answer as my declaration of array is different.

Please do let me know anyother way that I can use for this.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `.age` to get the attribute value and filter on it:

```js
arr = [
  {"name":"rahul","age":23},
  {"name":"Jack","age":22},
  {"name":"James","age":23}];
  
const count = arr.filter(x => x.age == 23).length;
console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below:

`arr.filter(item => item.age == searchValue).length`

Each item return object with `{name:string, age:number}` type. 
Then you should get `age` property of the item object and compare it with `searchValue`.

```js
arr = [
  {"name":"rahul","age":23}, 
  {"name":"Jack","age":22},
  {"name":"James","age":23}
]
let searchValue = 23;

console.log(arr.filter(x => x.age == searchValue).length)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
let persons = arr.filter(person => person.age===23)
console.log(persons.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

something like that ?

```js
const arr = 
      [ { "name": "rahul", "age": 23 } 
      , { "name": "Jack",  "age": 22 } 
      , { "name": "James", "age": 23 } 
      ] 

const countAge=x=>arr.reduce((a,c)=>a+=c.age==x?1:0,0)

console.log(countAge(23) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use destructuring in filter method.

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "rahul", age: 23 },
  { name: "Jack", age: 22 },
  { name: "James", age: 23 }
];

const count = arr.filter(({ age }) => age === 23).length;

console.log(count);
```